# How to treat the different representations of a fraction (eg, $1/2$, $3/6$, $6/12$) differently?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have fractions like $1/2$, $3/6$, and $6/12$; all evaluate to $0.5$. However, we want to treat the fractions with larger denominators differently.

Is there any mathematical formula to transform these and treat the fractions in a different manner?

Comment: Linear algebra?

Comment: "*all evaluate to 0.5*"  Not only that, as fractions they all **equal** 0.5.  If you want to work in a scenario where these are treated as distinct, then you are not dealing with fractions or real or rational numbers.  You would be wanting to deal with tuples in $\Bbb R^2$ or higher... and talking about the tuples $(1,2)$ or $(6,12)$ etc.  What you do with these tuples is up to you.

Comment: Exactlly, you can think about fractions as tuples in $\mathbb{Z}^2$ up to some equivalence relación. Other than that there is not much to do...

Comment: What do you mean by "we want to treat the fractions with larger denominators differently."?  Why do we want do do that?  Differently how?

Comment: There's a concept of the "height" of a rational number. There are several different definitions, but it's normally defined for fractions in lowest terms.  But maybe one of these will serve your purpose:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Height_function

Comment: Let me add some more background. The numerator denotes how many times a user has performed a certain operation and the denominator is how many times the user was eligible. Low values in denominator implies that the user is a new user whereas high values in denominator implies that user is an old user. Since we are measuring the effectiveness of a process, we expect old users to be more compliant. Hence, we consider 6 out of 12 to be poor with respect to 1 out of 2. One simple way is to square the denominator. May we can look at Z-score but it means calculating for the whole population.